# Strongswan IPSEC Tunnel block traffic one way

Tags: debian, iptables, ipsec, strongswan

I've set up a working Site to Site IPSEC Tunnel with strongswan on a debian 9 machine. However I have a requirement about how the traffic should work : The network on Site A can send packets to Site B Network and receive acks. Site B can only communicate with Site A when a connection is open. Basically, Site A can access Site B but Site B can't access site A. The infrastructure schema is like so :

```
        SITE A                                              SITE B
NetA--------------GatewayA------Internet------GatewayB-----------------NetB
A.A.A.A/24  A.A.A.254  pub.lic.ip.A   pub.lic.ip.B  B.B.B.254     B.B.B.B/24
```

I only have access to Site A. Site B is on client side.

Now I need to restrict access from Site B to Site A. My first go was to put iptables on GatewayA to basically accept ESTABLISHED and RELATED packets from Site B and DROP everything else. Here are my iptables :

```
sudo iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state RELATED
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  A.A.A.A/24        B.B.B.B/24        policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
```

```
sudo iptables -L INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state RELATED
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
```

Here, the 3 first rules on each table are manually edited and the next ones are set up by strongswan/ipsec. On a test environment, i can ping from site A to Site B but not from Site B to Site A, which is what I want.

```
me@gatewayA:~$ ping A.A.A.1
PING A.A.A.1 (A.A.A.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from A.A.A.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.25 ms
64 bytes from A.A.A.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.32 ms
64 bytes from A.A.A.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.28 ms
64 bytes from A.A.A.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=1.56 ms
64 bytes from A.A.A.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=1.45 ms
```

```
me@gatewayB:~$ ping B.B.B.1
PING B.B.B.1 (B.B.B.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Now, for some reason, I need to restart ipsec :

```
sudo ipsec restart
```

Now i check my iptables :

```
sudo iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  A.A.A.A/24        B.B.B.B/24        policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state RELATED
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec proto esp
```

```
sudo iptables -L INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state RELATED
ACCEPT     all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        state ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  B.B.B.B/24        A.A.A.A/24        policy match dir in pol ipsec proto esp
```

As you can see, restarting ipsec changed the iptables and now I can ping in both ways.

So I was wondering if there was any way to achieve what I want, which is restrict access from Site B to Site A without affecting communications that goes from Site A to Site B. Maybe there is a way to define iptables within the strongswan configuration, or maybe change the priority of iptables rules so that they keep their order at reboot.

Comment: Why did you configure  `leftfirewall=yes`? If you disable that, strongSwan won't install any firewall rules and you are free to configure them as you like.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by ecdsa, I just needed to put `leftfirewall=no` in ipsec.conf so the iptables can have the behavior that I wanted.